# How to check when animation finishes if animation block is

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a controller which adds as subviews a custom `UIView` class called `Circle`. Let's call a particular instance of `Circle`, "circle".

I have a method in `Circle`, `animateExpand`, which expands the circle by animating the view.

In the following code (which lives in the controller) I want to `alloc` and `init` a circle, add it to a `NSMutableArray circleArray`, animate the expansion, and at the end of the expansion, i want to remove the object from the array. My attempt:

```
Circle *circle = [[Circle alloc] init];
[circleArray addObject:circle];
[circle animateExpand];
[circleArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:circle];  
[circle release];
```

The problem is `[circleArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:circle];` gets called before the animation finishes. Presumbly because the animation is done on a seperate thread. I cant implement the deletion in `completion:^(BOOL finished){ }`, because the `Circle` class does not know about a `circleArray`.

Any solutions would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Circle *circle = [[Circle alloc] init];
if (circle) {
    [circleArray addObject: circle];

    [UIView
        animateWithDuration: 1.0 // or whatever
        animations: ^ {
            // the animations in -animateExpand "belong to" this outer animation block
            [circle animateExpand];
        }
        completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
            [circleArray removeObjectIdenticalTo: circle];
        }];

    [circle release];
}
```

Comment: I see that would work. Except if I am gona do that I might as well move the whole animation code into the controller...

Comment: The `circleArray` stuff isn't part of the `Circle` class' interface, so (as you said in your question) there's no way for the latter to know about the former. You could modify `Circle` to accept a block argument which it then passes to its internal `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` call, but this is the general solution for what you want to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, there is no way just to stop current view animation. However if a new animation is applied to a view, it will stop the currently run one. In this case, before removing your circle, you may start very short animation cycle (say, 0.1 sec), which doesn't do much. And then execute remove.